# Can you freeze whole pomegranates to save them?

Tags: freezing, fruit

I recently purchased a whole case of pomegranates, and it's getting hard to stand after doing 10 in a day, so can I safely freeze them whole to preserve the quality of the fruit?

Comment: I wouldn’t - but that’s just a gut feeling. What are you doing with them?

Comment: I plan to use them like other berries I freeze.

Comment: Soft fruits and vegetables don't withstand freezing very well, unless you plan to somehow cook them afterwards, or incorporate them as part of other dish

Comment: You could have tried freezing one overnight to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot freeze them whole; the large fruit pod will turn into a disgusting mush when you thaw it.

You can, however, [freeze the pips](https://canyoufreeze.com/pomegranate-seeds/) quite well, and they are the part you eat anyway.

Comment: I've read you may eat the white stuff

Comment: I have no idea whether it's healthful or not, but it certainly doesn't taste good.

Comment: You might wanna consider actually cutting one of these pomegranates open before you go further with this?  It sounds like You've never eaten one before.

Comment: I've eaten several, and have 3 that still weren't cleaned yet which I'll treat as a treat over the next 2 weeks.